# Regular expression for finding multiple patterns from a given string

Tags: php, regex

I am using regular expression for getting multiple patterns from a given string.
Here, I will explain you clearly.

```
$string = "about us";
$newtag = preg_replace("/ /", "_", $string);
print_r($newtag);
```

The above is my code.

Here, i am finding the space in a word and replacing the space with the special character what ever i need, right??

Now, I need a regular expression that gives me patterns like

`about_us`, `about-us`, `aboutus` as output if i give `about us` as input.
Is this possible to do.
Please help me in that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And finally, my answer is

```
$string = "contact_us";
$a  = array('-','_',' ');
foreach($a as $b){
    if(strpos($string,$b)){
        $separators = array('-','_','',' ');
        $outputs = array();
        foreach ($separators as $sep) {
            $outputs[] = preg_replace("/".$b."/", $sep, $string);
        }
        print_r($outputs);  
    }
}

exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a loop to handle multiple possible outputs :

```
$separators = array('-','_','');
$string = "about us";
$outputs = array();
foreach ($separators as $sep) {
 $outputs[] = preg_replace("/ /", $sep, $string);
}
print_r($outputs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try without regex:

```
$string      = 'about us';
$specialChar = '-'; // or any other
$newtag      = implode($specialChar, explode(' ', $string));
```

If you put special characters into an array:

```
$specialChars = array('_', '-', '');
$newtags      = array();
foreach ($specialChars as $specialChar) {
  $newtags[]  = implode($specialChar, explode(' ', $string));
}
```

Also you can use just `str_replace()`

```
 foreach ($specialChars as $specialChar) {
  $newtags[]  = str_replace(' ', $specialChar, $string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly what you want to do I expect that you might want to replace any occurrence of a non-word (1 or more times) with a single dash.

e.g.

```
preg_replace('/\W+/', '-', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace the space, use \s

```
<?php

$string = "about us";
$replacewith = "_";
$newtag = preg_replace("/\s/", $replacewith, $string);
print_r($newtag);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that regexes are the good tool for that. However you can simply define this kind of function:

```
function rep($str) {
    return array( strtr($str, ' ', '_'), 
                  strtr($str, ' ', '-'),
                  str_replace(' ', '', $str) );
}

$result = rep('about us');

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Matches any character that is not a word character

```
$string = "about us";
$newtag = preg_replace("/(\W)/g", "_", $string);
print_r($newtag);
```

in case its just that... you would get problems if it's a longer string :)